# Reduce NodeJS start time for scripting

Tags: node.js

I sometimes use NodeJS for scripting. But even for the smallest program, NodeJS binary takes too long to spawn. For example:

```
time node  -e 'console.log("hi")'
hi

real    0m0.050s
user    0m0.048s
sys 0m0.003s
```

In languages like Ruby, I usually use `ruby --disable-gems -e 'puts("hi")'`, which drastically uses less time (~0.015 seconds instead of ~0.07 seconds with the option) which makes it suitable. Perl, Lua, MRuby are the ones that are the fastest. But I have a program in NodeJS. Waiting for ~0.050 seconds seems like forever to me...

So for small programs, that spawns with BASH script (say file extension stripper, random number generator, or something written in NodeJS that is used in a BASH script loop that iterates over thousands of files), or a BASH prompt entirely written in NodeJS, the startup time seems to be bugging me.

I only need basic standard library features like handling files, etc.

I don't want to use something like spidermonkey, which seems to be much faster, but doesn't have much features that I'm used to. I also want to avoid using JS C/C++ extension and such.

Is there a way to speed up the NodeJS boot time?

Comment: *Waiting for ~0.050 seconds seems like forever to me...*.  So, you're trying to take 1/4 second out of this (cut this 1/2 second load time in half)?  That's meaningful to your use case?  Honestly, I would think there are much more important things to spend your time on.  I'm not aware of any way to change the load time other than fast hard drive and fast CPU and plenty of memory (which allows for larger disk caches).

Comment: The usual answer is to do more in the interpreted language rather than relying on linux to launch 1000's of processes quickly.  i.e. do the loop in JS.  Maybe try deno as an alternate v8 runtime https://deno.land/